# Dealing with duplicate keys

Tags: python

I got the following error:

> attempting to use to_dict to index a multiple sequence FASTA file with duplicate keys.

Are there methods for working around duplicate keys in biopython? I was thinking to simply remove the duplicate entries, but I would need to delete the entire entry associated with the keys.

Comment: Hi @Mike are you looking to rename the duplicate keys?

Comment: yes, I was thinking of appending the keys with digits incrementally or something? The keys are uniprot IDs, but the renamed duplicates wouldn't do anything harmful to my output. Might just be best to remove them using a set method or something. Still quite new to this.

Comment: Removing keys via a dictionary is easy, it should be automatic (they will overwrite). Pandas will enable duplicate keys are preserved by shifting the index

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Biopython deliberately does not allow duplicate keys with `.to_dict()`, e.g.

Input file:

```
$ cat test.fa 
>1
ATG
>2
AAA
>1
CG
```

Code:

```
from Bio import SeqIO

print(SeqIO.to_dict(SeqIO.parse("test.fa", "fasta")))
```

Traceback:

```
  File "script.py", line 3, in <module>
    print(SeqIO.to_dict(SeqIO.parse("test.fa", "fasta")))
  File "/path/lib/python3.7/site-packages/Bio/SeqIO/__init__.py", line 789, in to_dict
    raise ValueError("Duplicate key '%s'" % key)
ValueError: Duplicate key '1'
```

However, you can easily write your own function, e.g.:

```
from Bio import SeqIO

def to_dict_remove_dups(sequences):
    return {record.id: record for record in sequences}

print(to_dict_remove_dups(SeqIO.parse("test.fa", "fasta")))
```

Output:

```
{'1': SeqRecord(seq=Seq('CG', SingleLetterAlphabet()), id='1', name='1', description='1', dbxrefs=[]), '2': SeqRecord(seq=Seq('AAA', SingleLetterAlphabet()), id='2', name='2', description='2', dbxrefs=[])}
```

Alternatively, you Biopython's `.to_dict()` accepts a `key_function` argument, e.g. if you wish to make all the headers unique

```
from Bio import SeqIO
from itertools import count

c = count()

print(SeqIO.to_dict(SeqIO.parse("test.fa", "fasta"),
                    key_function = lambda x: f"{x.id}_seqNum{next(c)}"))
```

Output:

```
{'1_seqNum0': SeqRecord(seq=Seq('ATG', SingleLetterAlphabet()), id='1', name='1', description='1', dbxrefs=[]), '2_seqNum1': SeqRecord(seq=Seq('AAA', SingleLetterAlphabet()), id='2', name='2', description='2', dbxrefs=[]), '1_seqNum2': SeqRecord(seq=Seq('CG', SingleLetterAlphabet()), id='1', name='1', description='1', dbxrefs=[])}
```

Comment: thank you; return {record.id: record for record in sequences} so the expression garners us only unique IDs it seems, is this the case?

Comment: Well, obviously it does, but I guess my question is, what is determining the order (in the first solution)?

Comment: @Mike The last key,value pair is nearly* always retained *https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39678672/is-a-python-dict-comprehension-always-last-wins-if-there-are-duplicate-keys

Comment: Hi Chris, got it thank you!